# I can't change the value in the database - array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I need to update the comment status, i.e. the name of the "approve" field. To this end, I created the AJAX script also the backend seems correct because it receives a message after clicking the button. I don't know why I can't save the "approve" value to the database. Please help. I use NodeJS, MongoDB, Express, and EJS for frontend.
My database:
[image]

My  frontend:

```
 <% post.comments.forEach(function (comment) { %>

    <tr>
        <td> <%= comment._id %> </td>
        <td> <%= comment.username %> </td>
        <td> <%= comment.comment %> </td>

        <form method="post" onsubmit="return  doApprove(this);">
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<%= post._id %>" />
            <input type="hidden" id="comment_id" name="comment_id">
                 <td> <input class="approve-comment" type="checkbox" name="approve" value="true">
                <button class="btn btn-info" value="Approve"/>
                 </td>
        </form>
        <% }) %>
    </tr>

</table>

</div>
<script>
function doApprove(form) {
    var formData= {approve:form.approve.value};
    $.ajax({
        url: "/do-edit-comment",
        method: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
            formData._id =response._id;
            alert(response.text);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

My backend:

```js
app.post("/do-edit-comment", function (req,res) {
    blog.collection("posts").updateOne({
        "_id": ObjectId(req.body.id),
        "comments._id": ObjectId(req.body.id)
    },{
        $set: {
            "comments": {approve: req.body.approve}

        }
    }, function (error,document) {
        res.send({

            text: "comment approved"

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a single element from an array, what you need is the [`$[<identifer>`]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]) array update operator. For the scenario described in your question, the update query in the server should be something like this:

```
blog.collection("posts").updateOne(
    { "_id": ObjectId(req.body.post_id), },
    { $set: { "comments.$[comment].approve": req.body.approve } }, 
    { arrayFilters: [{ "comment._id": ObjectId(req.body.commentId) }] },
    function (error, document) {
        res.send({
            text: "comment approved"
        });
    }
)
```

**EDIT(Front-end issues/fix)**
So I figured there are some issues with the front end code too. This edit attempts to explain/fix those issues.

***Issues:***
1. The backend expects a `commentId` in the request object(req.body.commentId) to be able to identify the comment to update but you are not sending that from the front end.
2. The backend needs the id of the post to uniquely identify the post to update, but you are not sending that from the front end.
3. The `approve` value in the form data sent from the front-end is a string and it would always be `"true"`. This is not what you want, you want to send a boolean value(`true` or `false`) depending on if the checkbox is checked or not.

***Fix:***
Update the form template to this:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return doApprove(event);">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<%= post._id %>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="<%= comment._id %>" name="comment_id" />
    <td> <input class="approve-comment" type="checkbox" name="approve" value="true">
        <button class="btn btn-info" value="Approve"/>
    </td>
</form>
```

Changes:
- The `doApprove` handler attached to the submit event of the form is now called with `event` instead of `this`.
- I updated the value of the id attribute for the `input#name="comment_id"` element to the actual `comment._id` value.

And in the script tag, update the `doApprove` function to this:

```
function doApprove(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.target;
  var formData = {
    approve: form.approve.checked, // form.approve.checked would be true if the checkbox is checked and false if it isn't
    post_id: form.post_id.value, // The value of the input#name=post_id element
    commentId: form.comment_id.id, // The id attribute of the input#name=comment_id element
  };
  $.ajax({
      url: "/do-edit-comment",
      method: "POST",
      data: formData,
      success: function (response) {
          formData._id =response._id;
          alert(response.text);
      }
  });
  return false;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, it still doesn't change my status in the database. The backend seems correct, could you look at the front-end? Do I really do it properly? Comments are displayed one below the other and next to it is a checkbox.

Comment: Yh, just noticed some issues with the front end code. I would update the answer to include explanation of the issues and their possible fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can't change the value in the database. I get a message when I click on the button saying that "comment approved" as if everything was fine but it does not happen. I tried to change the line with the commentId code to "comment_id" so I have it in the database but it doesn't help. I wonder if this entry "{$ set: {" comments. $ [Comment] .approve ": req.body.approve}}," is correct, it is about [comment] and should there be something else next to "$" ? Thank you for everything you do.

Comment: Can we continue the discussion in this room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209637/tunmisekryniow, we would update this thread with whatever additional fix we discover.

Comment: Thank you for your interest but I can't write you back because I have too few reputation points. Could you send me a private contact to program like Discord or something else with a chat where we could continue the discussion?

Comment: For folks watching this thread; We were able to solve the issue via email/replit chat, the fix was to update the DB query in the backend to use the `post_id`(sent from the frontend) to uniquely identify the post to update. I updated the answer with this additional info.